# How can I run faster?

Tags: diablo-iii

So slow. I see that sprint was removed since *Diablo 2*, but is there *any* way to run faster (e.g., a run/walk toggle, a keyboard shortcut, a magic item perk, shrines, potions)? If so, what, and where can I get or do it?

I noticed each class has a [movement ability](http://www.diablowiki.net/Movement_ability) (leaping/teleport skills), but is it meant to replace running altogether? Is there an omni-character solution? All the Google hits are about "running" Diablo on your PC.

Comment: Did you know? Running in Diablo 2 reduced your defense to 0 (ranged and melee attacks will automatically hit, evasion still works though) and reduced your block to 1/3, but *everyone did it anyway*. See http://www.mannm.org/d2library/faqtoids/cth_eng.html#move and http://www.mannm.org/d2library/faqtoids/block_eng.html#grundblock respectively.

Comment: It's great to learn. BEACAUSE KNOWLEDGE IS POWER!

Comment: @Emerica J.I. JOE !!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard movement speed is as fast as it gets in Diablo 3. There is no run/walk toggle because you're now *always* running. Stamina no longer exists, and there's no real reason to ever move at a slower pace.

As for running faster, however, there are items that increase your movespeed. You are most likely to find this affix on boots, although it also exists much more rarely on other items.

[Here](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?816871-List-of-all-Affixes-with-Stats) is a partial list of affixes discovered so far and their properties. What you'll be looking for are boots that are Quick or Nimble.

[image: Nimble Boots]

Comment: The most noticeable way to run faster, though, is to use class-specific skills. Each class has at least one skill that helps with positioning and movement in combat.

Comment: Carrot on a stick?

Answer (score 3):

The Monk has a passive ability, [Fleet Footed](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/fleet-footed), which increases movement speed by 10%. Monks can also rune [Mantra of Evasion with Wind through the Reeds](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/mantra-of-evasion), which increases movement by 5%.

Most other classes have abilities that let them move more quickly for a time period, such as [Wrath of the Berserker](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/wrath-of-the-berserker) and [Smoke Screen (runed with Displacement)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/smoke-screen).

Here is a list of many such abilities: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/search?q=movement%20speed&f=static