# Is there any way to sprint?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run faster?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63546/how-can-i-run-faster)

Occasionally in dungeons, I find myself needing to backtrack to fully explore the level.  Since it doesn't appear that the enemies respawn, this is mostly just a matter of getting from point A to point B as quickly as possible.

I understand that some classes have movement abilities, however my Witch Doctor doesn't appear to be one of them.  Is there any class-agnostic way I can move *faster* through the game world?  A sprint, run, or "speed up" key, if you will?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to sprint. The only option you have is to equip items that increase your movement speed.

Comment: Unlike in Diablo 2, there is no way to sprint.  Your best bet is to use items that increase your movement speed (an attribute of many boots) or to use skills like the Barbarian's [Sprint][1] or the Monk's [Fleet Footed][2].


  [1]: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/sprint
  [2]: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/fleet-footed